# Site Scope Feature dependent on a Web Scope Feature

Tags: 2010, feature, feature-activation

On the root web for my site collection I need to make sure a web scope feature is turned on. In the feature EventReceiver I can turn on the feature progamtically. How can I stop the user turning the web feature off?

If the dependent feature was site scope I could add it to the featue manifest but I dont seem able to add a web scope feature there.

Comment: You can make the feature hidden so that the users cannot see it in the UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make it hidden so they cannot see it in the UI, but that's not really secure.

I suggest putting your end users in a security group that does not have permission to disable features or even see the feature list.